# Is there a way to tell if a HTML hex colour is light or dark in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, java, encodingutil

I have a Visualforce Colorpicker that allows users to set a background-color.

I have access to this in Apex as a string, e.g. '#FF0000'.  I want to know if this String is a dark color or a light color, to use either black or white font color.

I have been searching for a way to do this, and found threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679715/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-html-hex-colour-is-light-or-dark).  However, I have been unable to find a Salesforce specific way to do this, as Salesforce does not for example use java.awt.Color nor bytes as SF does not support it.

The convertToHex(); function in the [EncodingUtil](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) class looks like it might be useful, but I don't know what to do with the hexadecimal string.  Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: ported the code to apex below.**

Per the thread which you linked to, it appears pretty straightforward to adapt the code from the `java.awt.color` class, specifically the `RGBtoHSB` method and build it yourself in Apex. (Using `Decimal` instead of `Float` where appropriate)

You would then need to write some test code to cover this new code of yours, but it looks like a pretty straight forward porting of the Java implementation into Apex.

Source Code: [java.awt Color.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/Color.java.html)

You would then just grab the 2nd element from the returned array and compare it above or below 0.5 for light and dark (Saturation).

---

**HexUtils class** Used to convert the hex values of Red, Green, Blue into the integer representations

```
public class HexUtils {

    public class HexUtilsException extends Exception {}

    public static List<Integer> hexPairsToIntegers(String s) {
        // make sure we have an even number
        if (Math.mod(s.length(), 2) != 0) {
            throw new HexUtilsException('An even number of characters is required.');
        }
        // list that we'll return
        List<Integer> returnInts = new List<Integer>();
        // base 16 values
        String digits = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        // normalize the string
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        // matches an empty string that has the last match (\G) followed by two characters (..) before it ((?<= ))
        List<String> characterPairs = s.split('(?<=\\G..)');
        // iterate the pairs
        for (String characterPair : characterPairs) {
            // determine the integer value of the pair
            Integer val = 0;
            // split on every character in the pair
            List<String> characters = characterPair.split('|');
            // calculate the value of the new character
            for (String c: characters) { 
                Integer d = digits.indexOf(c);
                if (d != -1) {
                    val = 16 * val + d;
                } else {
                    throw new HexUtilsException('Non hex character found. "' + c + '"');
                }
            }
            // add it to the list
            returnInts.add(val);
        }
        return returnInts;
    }
}
```

**Color class** Ported code from Java Color class to Apex

```
public class Color {

    public static Decimal[] RGBtoHSB(Integer r, Integer g, Integer b, Decimal[] hsbvals) {
        Decimal hue, saturation, brightness;
        if (hsbvals == null) {
            hsbvals = new Decimal[3];
        }
        Integer cmax = (r > g) ? r : g;
        if (b > cmax) { 
            cmax = b;
        }

        Integer cmin = (r < g) ? r : g;
        if (b < cmin) { 
            cmin = b; 
        }
        brightness = ((Decimal) cmax) / 255.0;
        if (cmax != 0) {
            saturation = ((Decimal) (cmax - cmin)) / ((Decimal) cmax);
        } else {
            saturation = 0;
        }
        if (saturation == 0) { 
            hue = 0;
        } else {
            Decimal redc    = ((Decimal) (cmax - r)) / ((Decimal) (cmax - cmin));
            Decimal greenc  = ((Decimal) (cmax - g)) / ((Decimal) (cmax - cmin));
            Decimal bluec   = ((Decimal) (cmax - b)) / ((Decimal) (cmax - cmin));
            if (r == cmax) {
                hue = bluec - greenc;
            } else if (g == cmax) {
                hue = 2.0 + redc - bluec;
            } else {
                hue = 4.0 + greenc - redc;
            }
            hue = hue / 6.0;

            if (hue < 0) {
                hue = hue + 1.0;
            }
        }

        hsbvals[0] = hue;
        hsbvals[1] = saturation;
        hsbvals[2] = brightness;

        return hsbvals;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
String fontColor = '#0cf356';
List<Integer> fontIntegers = HexUtils.hexPairsToIntegers((fontColor.substring(1)));
system.debug(fontIntegers); // (12, 245, 86)

List<Decimal> hsbValues = Color.RGBtoHSB(fontIntegers[0], fontIntegers[1], fontIntegers[2], null);
system.debug(hsbValues); // (0.386266..., 0.951020..., 0.960784...)

Decimal brightness = hsbValues[2];
// 0 is dark, 1 is light
if (brightness < 0.5) {
   // use a bright background
    system.debug('I am a dark color.');
} else {
   // use a dark background
    system.debug('I am light color.'); // 0.95 = 'I am light color.'
}
```

This code hasn't been regression tested and you'll need to write your own test coverage for it but it appears to work correctly based on my limited testing of it.